# how to check user is online or not in real TIME

Tags: php

I'm currently trying to display all online users on my SITE'S userpage using the php session variables. To do this, whenever a user logs in or out, a column in a database gets set to "1" or "0".. However this doesn't entirely work since the database doesn't get updated when the user closes their browser (and therefor destroys the session). So is there another way of checking if a certain sessionid is set??
I also want to know how the twitter and facebook handle this ?

Answer (score 4):

You almost have it. The way that the vast majority of sites deal with the issue is to have a table like you do, but they add a timestamp to it and update the timestamp when a new page is loaded.

When querying the table, you simply look for say the last five minutes of active users and they are the "live" users on the site.

Technically, you don't even need to keep the "logged in/out" value in that table. If they have been logged in within the lat five minutes, they are probably still about.

There is no guaranteed, sure-fire, totally bullet-proof way of checking if a user is there or not. You can do some tricky JS to ping on and off, you can add even more JS that will try to alert the db when the user navigates away from the page - but at the end of the day, you cannot do anything if a browser is closed unexpectedly, or if that user loses power, or network.

On top of that web browsing is by default stateless and doesn't maintain a connection to the user after the server has finished sending code. The best we can efficiently do is update a table when the user does something new and assume they will be around for a few minutes at least.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't checked but Twitter and Facebook most likely have Javascript code which notifies the server when somebody closes the page, probably coupled with a periodic heartbeat and timeout.

Check the [onunload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onunload) and [XMLHTTPRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to see how you can make a request to your PHP application notifying of an user leaving (a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) might help you do this much more easily).

Comment: i knows and applied this but what i do when the browser is accidentally closed or user directly cut off the power supply , there are many other co-incidence like this.

Comment: That's what the heartbeat is for, there is no way for you to know if a computer is suddenly disconnected without having a constant or periodic connection and monitoring whenever it's closed.

Answer (score 0):

Add a field "last_visit" to user's Table and update it every time when user visit your site

When user login to your site find "last_visit" time and current time,after that use this function

```
   $time_period = floor(round(abs($current_time - $last_visit)/60,2));
if ($time_period <= 10)
                    $online_offline_status = 1;  
                else 
                    $online_offline_status = 0;
            }
```

and then print your final result

```
    <?php if (
$online_offline_status == 0){ ?> 
<span style="color:#FF0000;">Offline</span> 
<?php } else if ($online_offline_status == 1) {?> 
<span style="color:#669900;">Online</span> 
<?php }?>
```